# WCF Return list of baseclass objects containing derived class

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I've got a function returning all snakes. Looks like this and works fine:

```
// Function that returns JSON list of snakes
public List<Snake> GetSnakes()
{
    var snakes = new List<Snakes>();
    snakes.Add(new Snake { Length = "10.2" } );
    return snakes;
}
```

Now I got a bunch of animals with different properties, and I dont want to make a list for each one of them. I would like something like this:

```
public class AnimalService : IAnimalService
{
    private List<Animal> animals = new List<Animals>();

    public List<Animal> getSnakes()
    {
        animals.Add(new Snake { Name = "Snake" } );
        return animals;
    }

    public List<Animal> getPigs()
    {
        animals.Add( new Pig { Weight = "100" } );
        return animals;
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work. When I add a derived class to my animal list, the WCF service stops producing JSON for that function and returns nothing. No errors or anything but no results. How can I achieve what I want? One list containing return set of animals, doesn't matter what type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a `KnownTypeAttribute` to your `Animal` class for each subclass you'd like to have serialized:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Snake))]
[KnownType(typeof(Pig))]
public class Animal 
{
}
```

Comment: This worked! But I do get an akward json property, something like this: "__type":"Snake:#AnimalDatabase.Snakes". You know how to remove this?

Comment: The data comes from a database, but I dont have any property named __type

Comment: @Hasslarn That's a side effect of the `DataContractJsonSerializer` distinguishes between different C# classes. I don't think you can without writing a different serializer which can be done, but it's a fair amount of work.

Comment: Might it be possible to manually remove it after serialization?

Comment: I ended up using JSON.Net for serialization, it doesn't have the type property